# Getting error: "Missing ) after argument list. (line 8, file "Code")"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am getting this error: "Missing ) after argument list. (line 8, file "Code")"
When I run my code.

I've tried to switch around the single quotes around ProfileNav-value to double quotes and that did not work either. When I paste the exact function in line 8 into a shoot sheet cell, it works but google scripts does not let me run it.

```
function daily() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("BT");
  sh.insertRowAfter(2);
  sh.getRange("A3").setFormula('=TODAY()');
  sh.getRange("D3").setFormula('=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN("",REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTXML(C1,"//@content"),2),",",)),"(\\d*\\.*\\d+)([km]*)")),"\\.",),"k","00"),"m","00000"))');
  sh.getRange("E3").setFormula('=(D3-D4)/D3');
  sh.getRange("B3").setFormula('=query(IMPORTXML($D$1,"//span[@class='ProfileNav-value']/@data-count"),"limit 1 offset 2")');
  sh.getRange("C3").setFormula('=(B3-B4)/B3');

}
```

Looking for a way for line 8 to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the single quotation marks. This is done with a `\`.

```
sh.getRange("B3").setFormula('=query(IMPORTXML($D$1,"//span[@class=\'ProfileNav-value\']/@data-count"),"limit 1 offset 2")');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the single quotes in this by putting a `\` in front of each of them:

sh.getRange("B3").setFormula('=query(IMPORTXML($D$1,"//span[@class=\'ProfileNav-value\']/@data-count"),"limit 1 offset 2")');